# SQL query to merge rows

Tags: sql

I have an excel spreadsheet which pulls records from SQL. I want to combine the records and sum the qty field of matching records. I tried adding a select(sum) and group by command to my existing query but I didn't get very far as I have no real SQL experience. My table looks like this:

```
date.     |      tax description | tax%| tax 
1/02/2013          PST              5 %  2
1/02/2013          GST              7%   3
2/02/2013          PST             5%   2
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
date.     |       tax%           | tax(PST) | tax(GST)
1/02/2013       (5 +7 = )12%      2              3

2/02/2013             5%           2             0
```

can anyone help me what should the query look like?

I am really new to sql and i tried doing group by tax description and date but I am unbale to understand how to merge them at the end

Comment: wat is tax(pst) and tax(gst)

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, sum(tax%), sum(tax)
from table
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use group by...

```
 select date,sum (tax%), sum(tax) from table group by date
```

Comment: ahh.. i edited the question again.. in this i am not sure if groupBy is gong to work

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable (date1 VARCHAR(100), tax  int,taxper int)
GO
INSERT INTO #TestTable (date1, tax ,taxper )
SELECT '1/02/2013', 2,5
UNION ALL
SELECT '1/02/2013', 3,7
UNION ALL
SELECT '2/02/2013', 2,5
UNION ALL
SELECT '2/02/2013',10,12
UNION ALL
SELECT '2/02/2013', 20,22
GO

SELECT
date1,
'('+STUFF((
SELECT  '+ ' + convert(varchar(10),tax)
FROM #TestTable
WHERE (date1 = tbl.date1)
FOR XML PATH (''))
,1,2,'')+')='+ convert(varchar(20),sum(tax)) AS tax
,
'('+STUFF((
SELECT  '+ ' + convert(varchar(10),taxper)
FROM #TestTable
WHERE (date1 = tbl.date1)
FOR XML PATH (''))
,1,2,'')+')='+ convert(varchar(20),sum(taxper)) AS taxper

FROM #TestTable tbl
GROUP BY date1
GO
DROP TABLE #TestTable
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to:
1. transpose PST and GST records into tax(PST) and tax(GST) columns
2. and then SUM() the table by date

**Step 1.** Transposed table with additional columns  tax(PST) and tax(GST), **but without SUM by  date:**

```
date.     |      tax description | tax% | tax(PST)  |  tax(GST) 
1/02/2013          PST              5 %    2              0
1/02/2013          GST              7%     0              3
2/02/2013          PST              5%     2              0
```

You can get such a table by adding tax(PST) and tax(GST) columns with conditional subqqueries based on tax_description like this:

```
select date, tax description, tax%, 
       case
             when t.tax_description= 'PST' then
              t.tax
             else
              0
           end as "tax(PST)",
       case
             when t.tax_description= 'GST' then
              t.tax
             else
              0
           end as "tax(GST)"
from table t
```

**Step 2.** And now the transposed table **but also with SUM by  date:**

```
date.     |   tax% | tax(PST)  |  tax(GST) 
1/02/2013      7%     2              3
2/02/2013      5%     2              0
```

Here we just add SUM() aggregation by date to the sql from step 1:

```
select date, sum(tax%) as "tax%", 
       sum(case
             when t.tax_description= 'PST' then
              t.tax
             else
              0
           end) as "tax(PST)",
       sum(case
             when t.tax_description= 'GST' then
              t.tax
             else
              0
           end) as "tax(GST)"

from table t
group by date
```